# pip error: Bad interpreter when trying to run 'pip install ...' on OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

I am trying to install a fresh version of virtualenv (there is some problem with the path that python has stored in sys.executable) and it turns out there is another problem that actually seems related.

When I try to run `pip install virtualenv`, I get this output:

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4: 
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Now my original point in reinstalling virtualenv is that I keep getting this error when I run `virtualenv venv`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 994, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1288, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4'
```

As a sidenote that may be relevant, rather than using the default installed python3, I brew-installed a python3 with a brewed openssl (an application required it) and placed the path of the brewed python3 at the top of my `/etc/paths`.

I have tried to install and uninstall python multiple times without any success and am completely at a loss of what the problem could be. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
After @cel 's suggestions, it turned out that the head of my pip file (located at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip`) was set to hardcode a python version as so `#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4`. I changed this to the output of `which python` which was `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python`

This allowed me to succesfully create a virtualenv once again. Thanks!

Comment: does `echo $PYTHONPATH` print anything?

Comment: It does not, I just get an empty line

Comment: I have python2.7 installed under a similar scheme (path in /etc/paths, etc.)

Comment: What is the output of  `head -1 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip`?

Comment: Also the output of `python -E -m pip -V` and `python -E -m pip -V` may be interesting.

Comment: `$ head -1 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip`
`#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.4`
hmmm I'm remembering that I may have edited something like this. I'm going to try changing this to the python version that is in the python2.7 cellar

Comment: `$ python -E -m pip -V`
`pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`
Btw you entered the same command twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90954/discussion-between-cel-and-okuza).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a similar problem when I used HomeBrew to upgrade my python from version 3.5.2 to version 3.6.0. HomeBrew updated the symlink `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/bin/pip3` but my `/usr/local/bin/pip` was still using the old script and it was pointing to the python interpreter at `/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5`.

My course of action was as follows:

1. Unlinked `/usr/local/bin/pip` and updated it to point `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/bin/pip3`.
2. Created a new symlink `/usr/local/bin/pip3.5` that pointed to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pip3` and updated the header of pip3.5 script to point to the python interpreter at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3.5`
3. Followed the same procedure for `virtualenv`.

P.S. Initially I didn't face this problem with `virtualenv` since I was using it with the `-p` option.